# Creating expression tree for accessing a Generic type's property

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression-trees

I need to write a generic method which takes the instance of the generic type and the property name in string format and return an Expression tree

I need to convert a simple lambda expression

```
a => a.SomePropertyName
```

where `a` is generic type which **will have a property** by the name `SomePropertyName`

I know that we can get the property information using the following reflection code

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = a.GetType().GetProperty("SomePropertyName");
```

This might be very simple, but I'm not well versed with Expression trees, If there is a similar question, please link it and close this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the parameter type and return type aren't known in advance, you may have to use some `object`, but fundamentally this is just:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
    Expression.Convert(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(
             Expression.Convert(p, a.GetType()), propName), typeof(object)), p);
```

If the input and output types are known, you can tweak the `Func<,>` parameters, and maybe remove the `Expression.Convert`. At the extreme end you can get a lambda *without knowing the **signature** of lambda*, via:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(a.GetType());
var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, propName), p);
```

Comment: can't we pass the type to Func by using reflection to get the types of `a` and the property `SomePropertyName` ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna the second example has the lambda code figure out all the types for you, but: if you use the full generic version, you need to know the property type *statically*. Hence why I used `object` in the first example, because at least that will always work. If you had a generic method that took `TArg` and `TResult`, then you could build an `Expression<Func<TArg,TResult>>`, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(a.GetType(), "x");
var body = Expression.Property(p, "SomePropertyName");

Expression.Lambda(body, p);
```

Comment: in the first line what is "x" ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna just the name of the parameter. In your `a => a.SomePropertyName` example, it is the `a`.

Comment: As Marc says, it is the name of the parameter. It could actually be ommitted, it is not really necessary to specify it here.