# Build a Generic Expression Tree .NET Core

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, lambda, expression-trees

Hello Community i am aware of this might be a possible duplicate.

[How do I dynamically create an Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate from Expression<Func<MyClass, string>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094489/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-expressionfuncmyclass-bool-predicate-from-ex)

https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/

[How to create a Expression.Lambda when a type is not known until runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801165/how-to-create-a-expression-lambda-when-a-type-is-not-known-until-runtime)

[Creating expression tree for accessing a Generic type's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500604/creating-expression-tree-for-accessing-a-generic-types-property)

There are obviously too many resources.

I am still confused though. 
Could someone provide a clearer picture of what is happening in the below code.
Below i have provided some comments to help my understanding.

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseParametersToFilter<T>(string parameters)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> finalExpression = Expression.Constant(true); //Casting error

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
                return finalExpression;

            string[] paramArray = parameters.Split(","); //parameters is one string splitted with commas
     ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "viewModel"); //Expression Tree

            foreach (var param in paramArray)
        {
            var parsedParameter = ParseParameter(param);
            if (parsedParameter.operation == Operation.None)
                continue; // this means we parsed incorrectly we TODO: Better way for error handling

            //Property might be containment property e.g T.TClass.PropName
            Expression nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, parsedParameter.propertyName);
            //Value to filter against
            var value = Expression.Constant(parsedParameter.value);
            Expression comparison;
            switch (parsedParameter.operation)
            {   //Enum
                case Operation.Equals:
                    comparison = Expression.Equal(nameProperty, value);
                    break;
                    //goes on for NotEquals, GreaterThan etc
            }
            finalExpression = Expression.Lambda(comparison, argParam);// Casting error
        }

        return finalExpression;
    }
```

The above obviously is not working.

This is returned to linq query like this `IEnumerable<SomeModel>.Where(ParseParametersToFilter.Compile())`

I understand my mistake is a casting mistake.
**How could i fix this?**

After @Jeremy Lakeman answer i updated my code to look like this. Although the ViewModel i am using is quite complex. I have provided a small preview at the end.

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseParametersToFilter<T>(string parameters)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> finalExpression = t => true;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
                return finalExpression;

            string[] paramArray = parameters.Split(","); //parameters is one string splitted with commas

            ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "viewModel"); //Expression Tree
            Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);

            foreach (var param in paramArray)
            {
                var parsedParameter = ParseParameter(param);
                if (parsedParameter.operation == Operation.None)
                    continue; // this means we parsed incorrectly TODO: Better way for error handling

                //Property might be containment property e.g T.TClass.PropName
                Expression nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, parsedParameter.propertyName);
                //Value to filter against
                var value = Expression.Constant(parsedParameter.value);

                switch (parsedParameter.operation)
                {   //Enum
                    case Operation.Equals:
                        body = Expression.AndAlso(body, Expression.Equal(nameProperty, value));
                        break;
                        //goes on for NotEquals, GreaterThan etc
                }
                body = Expression.AndAlso(body, argParam);
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, argParam);
        }

private (string propertyName, Operation operation, string value) ParseParameter(string parameter){...}
```

But now  i get the following Exceptions

When i pass the Status as property parameter:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'model.StatusEnum' and 'System.String'.

When i pass the User.FriendlyName parameter:

> Instance property 'User.FriendlyName' is not defined for type 'model.ReportViewModel'
>   Parameter name: propertyName

**Here is how my view model looks like!**

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public StatusEnum Status {get;set;}
    public UserViewModel User {get;set;}
}

public enum StatusEnum
{
    Pending,
    Completed
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public string FriendlyName {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i came up with and works pretty well, from my tests today.
Some refactoring may be needed. I am open to suggestions.

Please make sure to check the comments inside the code.

```
private void ConvertValuePropertyType(Type type, string value, out dynamic converted)
        {
            // Here i convert the value to filter to the necessary type
            // All my values come as strings.
            if (type.IsEnum)
                converted = Enum.Parse(type, value);
            else if (type == typeof(DateTime))
                converted = DateTime.Parse(value);
            else if (type is object)
                converted = value;
            else
                throw new InvalidCastException($"Value was not converted properly {nameof(value)} {nameof(type)}");
        }

private MemberExpression GetContainmentMember(ParameterExpression parameterExpression, string propertyName)
        {
            //propertName looks like this User.FriendlyName
            //So we have to first take T.User from the root type
            // Then the Name property.
            // I am not sure how to make this work for any depth.
            var propNameArray = propertyName.Split(".");
            if (propNameArray.Length > 1)
            {
                MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propNameArray[0]);
                return Expression.PropertyOrField(member, propNameArray[1]);
            }
            else
            { //This needs to make sure we retrieve containment
                return Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyName);
            }
        }
// ***************************************************************
// This is the core method!
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseParametersToFilter<T>(string parameters)
        {
            Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);
            ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), nameof(T));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, argParam); // return empty filter

            string[] paramArray = parameters.Split(","); //parameters is one string splitted with commas

            foreach (var param in paramArray)
            {
                var parsedParameter = ParseParameter(param);
                if (parsedParameter.operation == Operation.None)
                    continue; // this means we parsed incorrectly, do not fail continue

                //Get model
                //Get property name
                //Property might be containment property e.g T.TClass.PropName
                //Value to filter against
                MemberExpression nameProperty = GetContainmentMember(argParam, parsedParameter.propertyName);

                //Convert property value according to property name
                Type propertyType = GetPropertyType(typeof(T), parsedParameter.propertyName);

                ConvertValuePropertyType(propertyType, parsedParameter.value, out object parsedValue);

                var value = Expression.Constant(parsedValue);

                switch (parsedParameter.operation)
                {
                    //What operation did the parser retrieve
                    case Operation.Equals:
                        body = Expression.AndAlso(body, Expression.Equal(nameProperty, value)); 
                        break;
                    //goes on for NotEquals, GreaterThan etc

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, argParam);
        }

private (string propertyName, Operation operation, string value) ParseParameter(string parameter){...}
```

This worked very good so far.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to turn something like `"a==1,b==3"` into `viewModel => viewModel.a == 1 && viewModel.b == 3`?

I think you're already pretty close, you just need add the `&&` (or `||`), and always create a lambda;

```cs
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> ParseParametersToFilter<T>(string parameters)
    {
        ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "viewModel"); //Expression Tree
        Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)){
            body = parameters.Split(",")
                .Select(param => {
                   var parsedParameter = ParseParameter(param);
                   // ... as above, turn param into a comparison expression ...
                   return comparison;
                })
                .Aggregage((l,r) => Expression.AndAlso(l, r));
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, argParam);
    }
```

And if this is for passing to entity framework, don't compile it or you'll only be able to evaluate it client side.

Comment: What you have provided is very promising.It works on a level.I get Argument Exception it cannot translate the Enums and containment properties.

Comment: This is supposed to happen client side. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Something like; `.Split(".").Aggregate(argParam, (l,r) => Expression.Property(l,r))`?

Comment: You'll need to convert datatypes and recursively resolve parameters. I recommend you declare some example `Expression<Func...>` and examine how the C# compiler has constructed their expression graphs.

Comment: How would i go about this? I get what is going wrong i am just not sure how to resolve them.

Comment: I managed to find the complete answer. Thank you for your time. Feel free to make any suggestions and edits to my answer.